# OpenShift post deployment initialisation script

Tags: openshift

I have an OpenShift 3.11 project using PHP and I would like to execute a script to configure the pod after it is deployed. The first thing the script will do is to create a symbolic link from the pod to the **PV** named **/storage** so that I can display the reports in the **reports** directory on the PV in a browser. I would also like to copy an image from my **image** directory - the image will indicate whether the application is running on the development system, the test system or production. The name of the appropriate image will be held in a config map which is tailored to each system.

I did consider **OpenShift's Pod Based Lifecycle Hooks** but they appear to run in a separate pod to the application that is deployed so the symbolic link will not be created in the application pod. The **OpenShift** documentation mentions you can change your image's **ENTRYPOINT**. The example shows running a **Java** application however I still require the **PHP** and **Apache** image to be deployed in addition to creating the symbolic link and copying the image.

Is it possible to perform post deployment configuration of a pod in **OpenShift** and if so how is it done?

Comment: Are you looking for container lifecycle hook - "PostStart".  Details are explained in following link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did read about lifecycle hooks and the post hook however the following page

https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/using-post-hook-to-initialize-a-database

indicates the post lifecycle hook runs in a different pod to the application. This will work for a database but not when creating symbolic links as the link will be created in the  post lifecycle hook pod and not the application pod.

Comment: I am referring to normal kubernetes object "kind: Deployment" with which hook can be executed within in same pod.  Openshift link is referring to "kind: DeploymentConfig" for which hooks will be executed in new pod.